# is there a way to have gvim automaximize on startup?

Tags: ubuntu, gvim

Setting lines and cols to 999 works only if the toolbars and menubars are there but if I remove them, it doesn't start maximized anymore. I usually have to alt+space and then hit x to maximize it. Is there a way to have this done automatically?

Here's what's in my vimrc right now:

```
set smartindent
set tabstop=8
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set number
set guifont=Consolas\ 10
syntax on
:colo wombat
filetype on
filetype plugin indent on
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set noerrorbells
set showmatch
set softtabstop=4
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set scrolloff=3
let Tlist_Exist_OnlyWindow = 1
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1
set guioptions-=L
set guioptions-=r
set guioptions-=m
set guioptions-=T
set lines=999 columns=999

map <c-j> <c-w>j
map <c-k> <c-w>k
map <c-l> <c-w>l
map <c-h> <c-w>h
nnoremap <silent> <C-N> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-T> :Tlist<CR>
```

I just figured out that the :simalt ~x does exactly what I'm describing here but it doesn't work under linux. I get a command not available in this version error.

EDIT: After lots of googling, it seeems that this is a vim-gtk bug with no fix yet.

Answer (score 1):

with [fluxbox](http://www.fluxbox.org/) as the windowmanager you could setup a rule which would maximize any number of gvim-instances upon creation. read `man fluxbox-apps` if you are using fluxbox.

a more general or windowmanager-independent approach is to use [devilspie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/) which allows you to setup some matching rules to identify windows and then apply actions onto them.